# Recyclerview no adapter attached skipping layout Android

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

Here is my code of adapter. Let me know if full adapter code, or some more code snippet is required

```
public class PostAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PostAdapter.PostViewHolder>{

    private Context context;

    public PostAdapter(Context context, List<Item> items) {
        this.context = context;
        this.items = items;
    }
```

Comment: share your `RecyclerView` item layout, and the calling `fragment/activity`

Comment: Check this is your solution:- https://stackoverflow.com/a/31850100/3974530

Answer (score 0):

You are having that warning because you have not set an adapter for your recycler view.

```
PostAdapter adapter = new PostAdapter(getContext(),mItems);
mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Ensure that you have a layout manager too for your recycler view

```
mRecylerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
```